# Focus on a specific tab not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to put focus on a tab, which should depend on the language of the user

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NoteTextViewModels.Count(); i++)
    {
      var languageId = @Model.NoteTextViewModels[i].LanguageId;
      var imageName = string.Format("FlagSmall_{0}.gif", languageId);
      var userLanguageId = ((WebTrial.Controllers.ControllerBase)ViewContext.Controller).LogonInfo.LanguageId;
      var temp = languageId == userLanguageId ? "TabShow": string.Empty;                
      <li class="@temp">
        <a href="#@languageId">
          <img src="@Url.Content("~/Graphics/" + imageName)" />
        </a>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
```

And this is the js code that should add focus to the specific tab:

```
var tabs = $("#tabs li");
var target = $("#tabs li.TabShow");
var languageIndex = tabs.index(target);

$("#tabs").tabs({ selected: languageIndex });
```

So basically, the relevant li gets the class name: `TabShow`, and this is the one that should be in focus. There is no error or anything, it just doesn't work. The focus is always on the first tab. And there will ALWAYS be only one `<li>` that has class `TabShow`

Do I have any error in my code, that I don't realize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) not `selected`

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: languageIndex });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rg5td4ta/)

Comment: Thanks, this was it. It's strange though. I have created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qL2W4/2407/  where I use selected, and here it works. How come?